# Egorov's and Lusin's Theorem in the space with infinite measure

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Both the fundamental Egorov's and Lusin's Theorem in measure theory are given on any  measurable space $X$ whose measure is  finite.

On the measurable space whose measure is infinite, does there exist  any condition such that both these fundamental theorems still hold?

Comment: The wikipedia page of Egorov's theorem has a counterexample on the real line…

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I edited the question.

Comment: That will depend on the exact formulations of the results you have in mind.

Comment: @ Michael Greinecker: Could you please give me more information? Does there exists any thing?